# AWS ECS Task fails with Docker Timeout Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I have created an ECS Cluster (EC2 Windows + networking) and tried to run a task to start running of my ECR (docker image), the task keeps showing 'Pending' status and after a while it gets changed to 'Stopped'. On verifying the status within the task's container, the status gets updated as "DockerTimeoutError: Could not transition to started; timed out after waiting 8m0s".

I tried looking in AWS docs and other blogs/forums on the internet, none of them helped to solve my issue. I also created an endpoint for logs as suggested in this site - https://charlesnagy.info/it/aws/aws-fargate-dockertimeouterror but that didn't help as well.

Has anyone ran into the same issue, and were able to resolve it?

The screenshots for my VPC setup, Route table, Security group are added below -

[image: My VPC setup is as below]

[image: My Route table setup is as below]

[image: My security group setup is as below]

The task setup JSON is -

```html
{
  "ipcMode": null,
  "executionRoleArn": null,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "environmentFiles": null,
      "logConfiguration": null,
      "entryPoint": null,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 7189,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "command": null,
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "cpu": 0,
      "environment": [],
      "resourceRequirements": null,
      "ulimits": null,
      "dnsServers": null,
      "mountPoints": [],
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "secrets": null,
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "memory": null,
      "memoryReservation": null,
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "stopTimeout": null,
      "image": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxxapi",
      "startTimeout": null,
      "firelensConfiguration": null,
      "dependsOn": null,
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "interactive": null,
      "healthCheck": null,
      "essential": true,
      "links": null,
      "hostname": null,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "pseudoTerminal": null,
      "user": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "dockerLabels": null,
      "systemControls": null,
      "privileged": null,
      "name": "xxxxxxxxxxapi"
    }
  ],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "memory": "512",
  "taskRoleArn": null,
  "compatibilities": [
    "EXTERNAL",
    "EC2"
  ],
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:ap-south-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:task-definition/xxx-webapi-td:9",
  "family": "xxx-webapi-td",
  "requiresAttributes": [
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
    }
  ],
  "pidMode": null,
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "EC2"
  ],
  "networkMode": null,
  "cpu": "512",
  "revision": 9,
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "inferenceAccelerators": null,
  "proxyConfiguration": null,
  "volumes": []
}
```

Comment: You have to provide exact details of your VPC setup, task settup, security groups, route tables and other related info.

Comment: Are you suggesting to provide the details of those here?

Comment: Where else? You made question on SO. Timeout indicates some networking  setup issue. Without such details, one can only speculate what could be the cause.

Comment: Added the necessary details now.

Comment: If this is EC2 launch type, do you have working instances registered with the cluster? Can you access them?

Comment: Yes, I could see the EC2 instance attached to the cluster, and the instance is currently in running status. However, I can't RDP into it as the instance was created by the cluster itself as I used the 'EC2 Windows + Networking' template to create the cluster. I don't have the password or key-pair to RDP into the instance.

Comment: Any particular reason for using windows? Linux is more common in ecs.

Comment: No particular reason, I am new to AWS and ECS, as I don't have much background working on Linux, I chose the Windows EC2 template. Do you see any issues with any of the VPC/RT/Task def setup?

Comment: Then if this is no requirenemnt, I would look at ECS Fargate. It is serverless version of ECS. Have you conisdered that?

Comment: Yes, I will be using that next, if this is not going to get resolved. Thanks.

Comment: Well yeah, I see this now - "Windows containers are only supported for tasks that use the EC2 launch type. The Fargate launch type isn't currently supported for Windows containers.", hence I can't run my image on Fargate, as my image was built as a Windows container. I am now forced to use EC2 Windows.

Comment: Look at this: https://aws.amazon.com/es/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-fargate-docker-timeout-error/

Maybe you need to create a VPC Endpoint